# AndroidStudio 3.2 slow startup on Mojave

Tags: macos, android-studio-3.0, macos-mojave

I downloaded the last version of Android Studio for my mac.
It took about 60 seconds to startup without any project to index!

I've modified the vm option file in this way

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx2560m
-XX:MaxPermSize=700m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=480m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djna.nosys=true
-Djna.boot.library.path=

-da
-Xverify:none

-XX:ErrorFile=$USER_HOME/java_error_in_studio_%p.log
-XX:HeapDumpPath=$USER_HOME/java_error_in_studio.hprof
```

But it's still the same

Any suggestion will be appreciated

MacBook Pro specs :

```
MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014)
Processor : 2,5 GHz Intel Core i7
RAM : 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
Graphics : Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB
Storage : SSD 500GB
```

Comment: if I delete the cached folder from /Users/username/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio it stats normally

Comment: the problem seems connected to the empty folder /Users/username/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio/tmp if the folder is present, the start up is slow, else is very quick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by adding my Mac hostname on the /etc/hosts file mapped to the 127.0.0.1 address as well as the ::1 like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost Macbook-1389.local
::1         localhost Macbook-1389.local
```

It seems to depend on JVM. Probably it takes a long time to resolve ip-address for localhost.

Fast solution

```
sudo sed -i bak "s^127\.0\.0\.1.*^127.0.0.1 localhost $(hostname)^g" /etc/hosts
sudo sed -i bak "s^::1.*^::1 localhost $(hostname)^g" /etc/hosts
sudo ifconfig en0 down
sudo ifconfig en0 up
```